# How can I add filtered result in list using LINQ or EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In The following Code I want to add a filtered list in my result variable:-

```
public JsonResult FetchDataForEdit()
    {
        int IDtoEdit = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["IDtoEdit"]);
        string MyTableName = Convert.ToString(TempData["MyTableName"]);

        try
        {
            Type tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
            switch (MyTableName)
            {
                case "CourseTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseTbl);
                    break;
                case "CourseDescTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
                    break;
                case "CourseSubDesc":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseSubDesc);
                    break;
                case "InternTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(InternShip);
                    break;
                case "ContactTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(Contact);
                    break;
            }

            using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
            {
                var results = new List<object>();
                foreach (var item in db.Set(tableType))
                {
                    //Want to Add result for selected IDtoEdit here like (db.Set(tableType).Where(x=>x.Id==IDtoEdit))
                    results.Add(item);
                }

                return new JsonResult { Data = results, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
            return new JsonResult { Data = "Not Found", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }

    }
```

As you can see I'm passing the Table Name and IDtoEdit in the JsonResult. Thus I'm fetching all records from the database in the 'results' var.
But I'm not able to filter my 'results' based on the where condition. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: What do you mean you "aren't able to"? What happens if you try?

Comment: I tried this way :-  `var results = new List<object>();
                    results= db.Set(tableType).Where(x => x.Id == IDtoEdit);` But giving me error :- dbset does not contain a definition for where

Comment: What can I use to fetch the required conditional result when I cannot use 'Where'?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're operating on a generic set, using the traditional LINQ `Where` extension method won't work. The ideal solution would be to modify your program structure and not have to deal with the generic set at all.

If you want to stick with your current program structure, your best bet would be to use the [`System.Linq.Dynamic`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) package, which allows you to define your queries as text. Your code will look something like this:

```
var result = db.Set(tableType).Where("Id = @0", IDtoEdit);
```

Some extra Dynamic Linq [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

Comment: Thanks for your reply . When I applied this code:- `using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
                {
                    var results = db.Set(tableType).Where("Id = @0", IDtoEdit); return new JsonResult { Data = results, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                }` It's giving me error:- The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.